# order of records is not proper in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a [simple test app running](http://hollow-beach-865.heroku.com/) on heroku.

But there is an issue in ordering of sub questions.

```
  class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sub_questions, :class_name => "Question", :foreign_key=>'parent_id'
    belongs_to :main_question, :class_name=> "Question", :foreign_key=>'parent_id'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_questions, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }
  end
```

As you can see from the content on that page: First question, second question , third question and etc.. It has same id in the data base and here is the loop

```
<% @question.sub_questions.each do |question| %>
     // my code....

<% end %>
```

The same code/database is working perfectly fine on my local machine.
Here is the screenshot from my database. Heroku has same one. I tried restarting the app and everything. Nothin

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the order you expect.

Example:

```
has_many :sub_questions, :class_name => "Question", :foreign_key=>'parent_id', :order => "id DESC"
```

Comment: It worked. But I am working on rails app from past 1 year and i never specified the order for ASC and it always worked for me. I have deployed some 4 applications on linode and even this app is working fine on linode. But not on heroku. My main concern is not heruko. My main concern is for ASC order should i specify order? M i missing this thing from day 1? Cause I always thought that rails automatically adjust thing in asc for these simple relationships.

Comment: it could be due to defaults on mysql and postgresql. Whatever, you should write and spec what you want to be sure about

Comment: Rails does not provide an automatic sort order. The default sort order is determined by the dbms. MySQL and sqlite use the primary key but postgres (used on Heroku) sorts by the most recently updated so apneadiving is perfectly correct. you need to override the default sort order